# Problem when migrating angular 7 with webpack/bin/config-yargs

Tags: angular, typescript

Despite the different answers on this topic I do not find a solution to solve this problem.

when I do a npm start, I get the following message :

```
  internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:583
    throw err;
     ^

   Error: Cannot find module 'webpack/bin/config-yargs'
```

I have tried the following solutions :

```
  npm install webpack-cli -D
  npm i webpack-dev-server
```

this is my package.json for the webpack

```
"webpack": "^4.29.6",
"webpack-cli": "^3.3.0",
"webpack-dev-middleware": "^2.0.6",
"webpack-dev-server": "^2.11.5",
"webpack-inline-manifest-plugin": "4.0.0",
"webpack-merge": "^4.2.1"
```

strangely I can not put the latest version of "webpack-dev-server" and "webpack-dev-middleware"

ng-version :

```
 Angular CLI: 7.3.6
 Node: 10.15.1
 OS: win32 x64
 Angular: 7.2.10
 ... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
 ... http, language-service, platform-browser
 ... platform-browser-dynamic, platform-server, router

 Package                           Version
 -----------------------------------------------------------
 @angular-devkit/architect         0.13.6
 @angular-devkit/build-angular     0.13.6
 @angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.3.2
 @angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.13.6
 @angular-devkit/core              7.3.6
 @angular-devkit/schematics        7.3.6
 @angular/cli                      7.3.6
 @ngtools/webpack                  1.10.0
 @schematics/angular               7.3.6
 @schematics/update                0.13.6
 rxjs                              6.4.0
 typescript                        3.3.4000
 webpack                           4.29.6
```

if you have a solution for this problem it would be great ?

Comment: I haven't done that upgrade yet, but have you attempted to delete your node_modules directory and then run npm install to rebuild it? Sometimes that helps with some similar issues I have had in the past.

Comment: @dmoore1181 sorry but i still have the same problem even after deleting node_modules